# The document was submitted successfully. Its location will change pending action from a site administrator

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, content-organizer, drop-off-library, content-organizer-rule

I am trying to upload a file to a document library which is a content organizer library and most of the files go to the correct library. But one particular file is routing to Drop-off library.

Below are the things I tried:

1. Created new rules.
2. De-activated and activated the dependent features in SharePoint site.

But, still I am unable to upload the file and getting same error:

[image]

Comment: Are you creating a rule correctly? Can you please add a screenshot of your rule too? Is will help us to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can move documents from one document library to another document library.

Users are redirected to the Drop Off Library when they try to upload content to libraries in this site that have one or more content organizer rules pointing to them.  So that means only after you create a content organizer rule point to the document library, the documents will be redirected to the drop off library.

Eg: you have LibraryA, LibraryB, Drop Off Library.

If you want to move the documents from LibraryA to LibraryB, you must create an content orgainizer rule pointing to LibraryB and also create an content orgainizer rule pointing to LibraryA.

If there is any problem, feel free to let me know.